# Multi Insert Functionality in React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I am using an application having backend in rails and front-end in react. I have a model Named Employee which has many fields so I have used bootstrap tabs to separate each group for better user experience. Now I am stuck at a point. I have two Tabs. First tab is showing personal information and second is showing bank information. Now employee can have many bank details so There should be a button that when clicked, renders another row for record insertion. I am unable to do this.

Below is my main component in which I am importing these two tabs information.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tab, Tabs } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import BankDetails from "./components/BankDetails";
import PositionalInformation from "./components/PositionalInformation";
import OtherInformation from "./components/OtherInformation";
import BranchAndPosition from "./components/BranchAndPosition";
const NewEmployee = () => {
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    branch_id: undefined,
    position_id: undefined,
    first_name: null,
    middle_name: null,
    last_name: null,
    maiden_name: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    phone: null,
    alternative_phone: null,
    country: null,
    city: null,
    zipcode: null,
    employment_type: null,
    supervisor_name: null,
    ist_supervisor: null,
    basic_salary: null,
    commission: null,
    gross_salary: null,
    tin_no: null,
    status: null,
    date_of_birth: null,
    gender: null,
    martial_status: null,
    ethic_group: null,
    supervisor_id: null,
    report_to: "",
    department_id: null,
    duty_type: null,
    hire_date: null,
    joining_date: null,
    termination_date: null,
    termination_reason: null,
    voluntary_termination: null,
    rehire_date: null,
    monthly_work_hours: null,
    pay_frequency: null,
    type: null,
    account_title: null,
    account_number: null,
    bank_name: null,
    branch_adress: null,
    sos: null,
    work_in_city: null,
    city_of_residence: null,
    work_permit: null,
    self_medical: null,
    family_medical: null,
    transportation: null,
    home_email: null,
    business_email: null,
    home_phone: null,
    business_phone: null,
    cell_phone: null,
    emergency_contact_person_name: null,
    emergency_contact_person_relation: null,
    emergency_contact: null,
    alternative_emergency_contact: null,
    emergency_home_phone: null,
    alternative_emergency_home_phone: null,
    alternative_emergency_phone: null,
    emergency_work_phone: null,
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("1");

  const handleTabSelect = (tabKey) => {
    setActiveTab(tabKey);
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    // Do any necessary validation before switching to the next tab
    setActiveTab((parseInt(activeTab) + 1).toString());
  };

  const handlePreviousClick = () => {
    // Do any necessary validation before switching to the previous tab
    setActiveTab((parseInt(activeTab) - 1).toString());
  };

  const data1 = {
    employee: {
      branch_id: formValues.branch_id,
      position_id: formValues.position_id,
      first_name: formValues.first_name,
      middle_name: formValues.middle_name,
      last_name: formValues.last_name,
      maiden_name: formValues.maiden_name,
      email: formValues.email,
      password: formValues.password,
      phone: formValues.phone,
      alternative_phone: formValues.alternative_phone,
      country: formValues.country,
      city: formValues.city,
      zipcode: formValues.zipcode,
      employment_type: formValues.employment_type,
      supervisor_id: formValues.supervisor_id,
      report_to: formValues.report_to,
      ist_supervisor: formValues.ist_supervisor,
      basic_salary: formValues.basic_salary,
      commission: formValues.commission,
      gross_salary: formValues.gross_salary,
      tin_no: formValues.tin_no,
      status: formValues.status,
      date_of_birth: formValues.date_of_birth,
      gender: formValues.gender,
      martial_status: formValues.martial_status,
      ethic_group: formValues.ethic_group,
      emp_bank_details_attributes: [
        {
          b_type: formValues.type,
          account_title: formValues.account_title,
          account_number: formValues.account_number,
          bank_name: formValues.bank_name,
        },
      ],
      emp_positional_information_attributes: {
        department_id: formValues.department_id,
        hire_date: formValues.hire_date,
        joining_date: formValues.joining_date,
        termination_date: formValues.termination_date,
        termination_reason: formValues.termination_reason,
        voluntary_termination: formValues.voluntary_termination,
        rehire_date: formValues.rehire_date,
        monthly_work_hours: formValues.monthly_work_hours,
        pay_frequency: formValues.pay_frequency,
      },
      emp_other_information_attributes: {
        sos: formValues.sos,
        work_in_city: formValues.work_in_city,
        city_of_residence: formValues.city_of_residence,
        work_permit: formValues.work_permit,
        self_medical: formValues.self_medical,
        family_medical: formValues.family_medical,
        transportation: formValues.transportation,
        home_email: formValues.home_email,
        business_email: formValues.business_email,
        home_phone: formValues.home_phone,
        business_phone: formValues.business_phone,
        cell_phone: formValues.cell_phone,
        emergency_contact_person_name: formValues.emergency_contact_person_name,
        emergency_contact_person_relation:
          formValues.emergency_contact_person_relation,
        emergency_contact: formValues.emergency_contact,
        alternative_emergency_contact: formValues.alternative_emergency_contact,
        emergency_home_phone: formValues.emergency_home_phone,
        alternative_emergency_home_phone:
          formValues.alternative_emergency_home_phone,
        alternative_emergency_phone: formValues.alternative_emergency_phone,
        emergency_work_phone: formValues.emergency_work_phone,
      },
    },
  };

  const saveEmp = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_EMPLOYEES_URL, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data1),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (data.status === 200) {
    }
  };

  const saveEmployee = () => {
    saveEmp();
  };

  const renderBankRow = () => {};
  return (
    <Tabs
      activeKey={activeTab}
      onSelect={handleTabSelect}
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        marginTop: "200px",
      }}
    >
      <Tab eventKey="1" title="Basic Information">
        <BranchAndPosition
          formValues={formValues}
          handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Button onClick={handleNextClick}> Next</Button>
      </Tab>

      <Tab eventKey="2" title="Bank Information">
        <BankDetails
          formValues={formValues}
          handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <Button onClick={handlePreviousClick} className="mr-2">
          Previous
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleNextClick}>Next</Button>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
export default NewEmployee;
```

Following is my bank component

```
import React from 'react'
import bank_types from "Data/Bank";
import { FormGroup, Input, Row, Col, Label } from "reactstrap";
const BankDetails = ({formValues, handleInputChange}) => {
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={3}>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label >TYPE</Label>
          <Input id="type" name="type" type="select" value={formValues.type} onChange={handleInputChange}>
            <option value="">Please Select Bank Type</option>
            {bank_types.map((type)=>{
              return <option value={type.value}>{type.name}</option>
            })}
          </Input>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>

      <Col md={3}>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label>Account Title</Label>
          <Input type="text" name="account_title" value={formValues.account_title} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>

      <Col md={3}>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label>Account Number</Label>
          <Input type="text" name="account_number" value={formValues.account_number} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>
     <Col md={3}>
        <FormGroup>
          <Label>Bank Name</Label>
          <Input type="text" name="bank_name" value= {formValues.bank_name} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
        </FormGroup>
      </Col>
      
    </Row>
  )
}

export default BankDetails
```

Comment: please provide code sandbox sample working code

Comment: My repos are private so code sandbox requires a pro version